# Change title of UItabbaritem in other view?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, multilingual, uitabbaritem

How do I change the UITabbaritem titles when starting the App?

I got a UITabBar with 4 tabs. I want the user to be able to change between two different languages. If the user chooses a different language I need to set a different title to the UITabbaritems. I know I can use `self.title = @"title";` but that only changes the current tabbaritem title. How can I change all the titles at once, on load, and when choosing a different language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved it with.

```
[[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] setTitle:@"Your title"];
```

Where index is your UITabBarItem index.

Comment: Works for me too. I wish this answer had a higher profile, I was searching for it for several hours!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all your UITabBarItem into an array, when the user tap the button, you need to loop through that array and set the title.

```
for (UITabBarItem *item in items) {
  item.title = @"WHATEVER HERE";
}
```

Comment: I think I understand where you are going with this. But can you be more specific? I tried to change the UITabBarItem of another view without getting a result. Where do I implement loop and do I need to change the title of the viewControllers or just the UITabBarItems? Thanks

Comment: In the buttonClicked: method that takes care of the event button is clicked, you put the loop. You can pass the array of UITabBarItem into the ViewController who holds the button

Comment: Thanks vodkhang, I will give it a go this weekend.